# Why is it that I can target a child node of a form element by simply referencing the name of the id, but I can't do the same with non-form elements?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById("form-test").termid.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

```html
<form action="searchname.php" id="form-test">
  <input type="search" name="term" id="termid" value="some rnadom value">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here, I am targeting the child node `input` by simply referencing its `id` as if it's a property of the parent node. The same thing doesn't work with non-form parent elements.

```js
alert(document.getElementById("ul-list").two.innerHTML)
```

```html
<ul id="ul-list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li id="two">Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Why is this not working? I didn't think that you can target a child node by just referencing its `id`, but apparently you can do it with form elements, but then why is the same thing not working with other elements?

Comment: I think it's because forms let you access form elements by ID. ULs don't have that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements <- this is what I'm thinking of

Comment: Forms are given special treatment in JavaScript to make it easier to write code that processes all the inputs.